# fstream file being rewritten

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I'm working on a program that will output a text file. Any time that I want to write to the file, I open it, `seekp()` to the end of the file, write to it, and close it. However it seems that each time a new write is performed, it is replacing all of the data that previously existed in the file.

```
output.open("output.txt", fstream::out);
output.seekp(0, ios::end);
output << "Record " << key << " does not exist.\r";
output.close();
```

Is this the proper way to append every write to the end of the file? Any ideas what might be causing the entire file to be rewritten would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `fstream::app` flag.

```
output.open("output.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);
```

Answer (score 2):

`fstream::out` always overwrites the data in the file. to append, use the module `fstream::app`