# Opening an existing text file erases its contents altogether

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am trying to open a text file (it has content). Every time I open it, the content of the file ends up being erased altogether, which I do not want.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter File name : ";
    cin >> filename;
    fstream file;
    file.open(filename, fstream::out);
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually you want `std::ios::in | std::ios::out`. `std::ios::app` *only* allows you to write to the end of the file--even if you seek to somewhere else in the file, any attempt at writing will seek to the end first, then do the writing. That's good for things like log files; not so good for most others.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but get in the habit of creating objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case that means changing `fstream file; file.open(filename, fstream::out);` to `fstream file(filename, fstream::out);`. Also, you don’t need to call `file.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fstream file being rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672785/fstream-file-being-rewritten)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `fstream::out` which discards everything which was previously present in the file, you should use `fstream::app` which will not delete the contents of the file and continue writing to it from its end.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream):

| Constant | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| app | seek to the end of stream before each write |
| binary | open in binary mode |
| in | open for reading |
| out | open for writing |
| trunc | discard the contents of the stream when opening |
| ate | seek to the end of stream immediately after open |
| noreplace (C++23) | open in exclusive mode |